# doc,docx file into pdf using shell_exec

Tags: php, laravel, libreoffice

i want to convert doc,docx file into pdf using libreofficec .i had found many question related to this but one of these not helpful to me so i post my qwestion over here 
here is my code

```
     $resume = Input::file('resume');
        $extenstion = 'pdf';
        $datafiles = 'Resume_'.str_random(10).'.'.$extenstion;
          $resume ->move(public_path('datafiles/APPL'), $datafiles);
```

how i can mere above code in this for ex i want to convert a file into pdf and then assign a $datafile after that i want to move this file  to this location datafiles/APPL or is there any way to assign $datafile directly to below code or eg

```
  shell_exec('start /wait soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir --savefile name as  $datafiles "./publicapp" "'.$resume.'"'); // is this possible or other correct way

  shell_exec('start /wait soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "./publicapp" "'.$resume.'"');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest wy is to use "unoconv":

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
doc2pdf respondus-docx-sample-file.docx
```

Comment: i want to rename also since i have more than 10k resume

Comment: Use the "-o" option

Comment: Or try using "writer -convert-to pdf:test.pdf file.docx"

Comment: what o option does

Comment: -o = output eg doc2pdf sample.docx -o sample.pdf

Comment: can you give me whole syntax i.e including -o